# How to change the legend position from a Venn Diagram using eulerr package?

Tags: r, legend, venn-diagram, eulerr

I am using the `eulerr` package and I want to change the legend position of my plot. I have been able to change it to the right, left, up, down... But I cannot change it to the top right.

```
library(eulerr)
fit <- euler(c("A" = 10, "B" = 5, "A&B" = 3))

plot(fit, quantities = TRUE, legend = list(labels = c("foo", "bar"), side="right"))
plot(fit, quantities = TRUE, legend = list(labels = c("foo", "bar"), side="left"))
plot(fit, quantities = TRUE, legend = list(labels = c("foo", "bar"), side="down"))
plot(fit, quantities = TRUE, legend = list(labels = c("foo", "bar"), side="top"))

plot(fit, quantities = TRUE, legend = list(labels = c("foo", "bar"), side="topright")) #it doesn't work
```

Does anyone know how to change the legend position to the top right?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Upon review of the `plot.euler.R` [file](https://github.com/jolars/eulerr/blob/master/R/plot.euler.R) of the `eulerr` package it checks to see if the legend is to be located only left, right, down, and top.

Comment: @Ben Oh thanks, I couldn't find the code of the function. Do you know if there is a similar package to `eulerr` where I could put the legend on the topright?

Comment: I'm not familiar with other packages like `eulerr`. You also could make a feature request on github.